# Why ModelState.IsValid always = false. Using asp.net core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Every time I get `ModelState.IsValid = false`.

I removed validation from the model and still the same issue.
When I commented the `ModelState.IsValid` I faced *data null* error, and when I removed the comment `ModelState.IsValid` always `false`.

**Model**

```cs
public class Actor
{
    [Key]
    public int ActorID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Full Name")]
    [Required (ErrorMessage ="This field is required")]
    [StringLength (50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage ="Full Name must be between 3 - 50 chars")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string ProfilePic { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bio")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Bio must be between 3 - 50 chars")]
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    //Relationships
    public List<Actor_Movie> Actors_Movies { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Function**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FullName, ProfilePic, Bio")]Actor actor)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _service.addActor(actor);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    else
    {
        return View(actor);
    }    
}
```

The `ModelState.IsValid` is always `false`.

Comment: Put the break point on the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and check `ModelState.Values` to see what values cause the `ModelState.IsValid` to return `false`. I suppose it might be items in the `Actors_Movies` list.

Comment: Create a separate ViewModel for the form that includes only the fields you need for the form submission. In this case, you can exclude the ProfilePic property from the ViewModel if it is not required for form submission.

Answer (score 2):

I found the error and I solved it, the error was in `Actors_Movies` value it's always null, I unfortunately added this input type as hidden in the View:

`<input asp-for="Actors_Movies" type="hidden" />`

Removing `type="hidden"` makes it work successfully.